# DDP protocol in native android app

Tags: android, meteor, ddp

I am developing a web platform with meteorJS.
Native android apps will also be connected to the server to display live data. I will therefore use meteor's ddp protocol for my apps and store the data in the sqlite db as I need them to be working offline.

For Android, the DDP client to use seems to be : https://github.com/kenyee/android-ddp-client

In the “Usage” section of the Readme (function broadcastSubscriptionChanged) , it seems that I can listen to changes in one collection and then upadting the whole collection if an update event is detected.
The thing is my collections are pretty heavy, lots of documents.
Do you know in what consists the refreshFields function? will it update every document in the collection? or only the ones that have changed?

I just want to make sure that my users won't have a 5min loading spinner everytime a document in a huge collection changes

Thanks a lot,
Victor

Answer (score 0):

This line implies that only the document with `_id === docId` will refresh.

```
mParties.get(docId).refreshFields();
```